# Passing strings as route parameters in Angular without encoding

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to pass a string using this code:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/systems', params.toString()]);
```

The route parameter is then appended to a URL for an API call. 
The `params.toString()` is `change_user=2258`. When it is sent through the browser however, it is changed to `change_user%3D2558` on the URL. When I use the developer tools to see what was sent to the API, it was changed to `NaN`.
How do I pass a string through a router, so that I can directly append it to my API string?

Edit: The variable `params` is of type `URLSearchParams()`. 
This is how I'm trying to extract the parameter:

```
this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
this.httpService.getSites(+params.get('params')))
.subscribe(sites => this.sites = sites);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So here was how I fixed it:

All I had to simply do was take out the `+` in the `+params.get()` call. Apparently what that does is try and convert it to a number. Now I am able to pass in my `params.toString()` directly.

Answer (score 6):

Add a route definition with a parameter as described [here in the Angular 2 routing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter)

```js
{ path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
```

### Option 1

You then will be able to navigate to the route with

```js
let id = 2258;
this.router.navigate(['/hero', id]);
```

And use the `ActivatedRoute` in `@angular/router` to extract the parameters as described [here in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action)

```js
let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

### Option 2

Use the `router.navigateByUrl()` methods ([documentation here](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#usage-2))

```js
router.navigateByUrl('/hero/2258');
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing, sorry I should have put that code.

Comment: Ok do you want it to be optional or required?

Comment: I have one parameter to be required, and a few to be optional. I'm aware of how to do this, but the issue is with what's being passed itself. The string I want to pass, is changing to something else; namely to `NaN`.

Comment: Actually, I just want one string I can directly append to my api call. For example: change_user=111&id=222&ect=111. My `params` variable already encapsulates that correctly, but when I pass it in the router, is when things get messed up.

Comment: yes I think it's because you are passing `params.toString()` which I presuming is resolving to `change_user%3D2558` as you say and `parseInt('change_user%3D2558')` is `NaN` so instead of `params.toString()` try a variable holding just `2258` as suggested in my middle code block :)

Comment: I see. That does work, but then I have to manually put the string back together for the API url. I'm basically trying to transfer some form data from one component to another that uses that data for an API GET request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149852/discussion-between-0mpurdy-and-ecain).